# Meteor: Store many objects in one object

Tags: mongodb, meteor

What is the optimal way to store a set of objects in a meteor collection?

E.g.

```
  Container.insert({
    name: "A",
    list: [obj1, obj2, obj3]
  });
```

It seems like container.list would return an array, but what if given obj1, I wanted to find the Container.name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give a precise answer without a schema for the objects in `list`, but imagine each had an `_id` property. Then you could do something like:

```js
let name = Container.findOne({'list._id': 'abcd'}).name;
```